# Processing Python screens

Tags: python, processing

I've made a program that allows you to choose a character but I'm stuck on using screens with processing.

From what I know using screens rewrites the whole screen but I want to keep some elements like the character choices you made and make sure you can use it.

So what I am trying to do is after you made your 4 choices you have to click the empty box to go to the next screen with only the choices you made.

Code:

```
def mousePressed():
    global choices,playerchoices
    print(choices)

if mouseButton == LEFT:

    if len(playerchoices) < 4 and screen1:
        for character in choices:
            if mouseX >= character['rectangle'][0] and mouseX <= character['rectangle'][2] + character['rectangle'][0]  and mouseY >= character['rectangle'][1] and mouseY <= character['rectangle'][3] + character['rectangle'][1] :
                (playerchoices.append(character))
                fill(100)  
                rect(character['rectangle'][0], character['rectangle'][1], character['rectangle'][2], character['rectangle'][3])


        for i in range(len(playerchoices)):
            fill(135)
            rect(420,90+(50 * i),150,50)
            fill(190)
            text(playerchoices[i]['name'] ,420,90+(50 * i),150,50)


    elif screen2:
        if 490< mouseX < 400 and 50 < mouseY < 50:
            Complete()
```

full code: https://github.com/jagmeet44/lesson-code

I hope someone can help me I've tried to just declare the screen with name but that only shows the console.

Comment: You appear to be using some kind of graphics module. Which one is it? Note also that the correct spelling is "character" not "charachter".

Comment: Is this one file? Is this being imported?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the different screens to be draw and use a variable to determine what screen needs to be draw. Create a function for the different screen. Elements that stay the same, like a menu can be defined in a separate function and drawn over another screen.

Below I created a basic setup, where the variable gameState holds which screen to be drawn. I also used a more flexible setup for drawing the options. This way you can calculate the position where the items have to be drawn and which one is clicked using the mouseX and mouseY.

There are different options to show the choices while still choosing. I implemented it by showing the options chosen, and removing those from the option-list. Clicking a chosen character, returns it to the options.

```
choices =["Spiderman","Hulk","BlackPanther","DrStrange","Thor","IronMan","CptnAmerica"]
playerchoices = []
gameState = 0 # gamestate hold the current fase of the game / current screen to be drawn
# 0 -> select team
# 1 -> team selected, review choices

def draw():
    background(220)
    fill(0)
    if gameState == 0:
        drawChoices()
    elif gameState == 1:
        reviewChoices()

def drawChoices():
    global choices, playerchoices
    # draw all options
    for i in range(len(choices)):        
        text(choices[i],50,20*i+20) # write names at x=50, and y dependent on list index
    # draw chosen
    for i in range(len(playerchoices)):
        text(playerchoices[i],400,20*i+20)  # write names at x=400, and y dependent on list index

def reviewChoices():
    global playerchoices
    for i in range(len(playerchoices)):
        text(playerchoices[i],50,20*i+20)  # write names at x=50, and y dependent on list index

def mousePressed():
    global choices,playerchoices, gameState
    if gameState == 0: # if selecting characters
        if mouseButton == LEFT:
            if mouseX >= 50 and mouseX < 350: # mouseX is on the list of names
                listIndex = (mouseY-20) // 20 #determine listindex based on mouseY
                if listIndex < len(choices): # if not clicked below the list
                    playerchoices.append(choices[listIndex]) # add character to selectedlist
                    choices.remove(listIndex) # remove character from optionlist
                if len(playerchoices) == 4: # if 4 characters chosen, move to next gamestate / screen
                    gameState = 1
            elif mouseX >= 400 and mouseX < 750: # mouseX is on the list of chosen-names
                listIndex = (mouseY-20) // 20 #determine listindex based on mouseY
                if listIndex < len(playerchoices): # if not clicked below the list
                    choices.append(playerchoices[listIndex]) # add character to optionlist
                    playerchoices.remove(listIndex) # remove character from selectedlist
```

Note: I do not have Processing with Python, so I have not tested this code. But if it doesn't work I'm sure you'll figure it out.